# WCF Client fails to connect to NetTcpBinding Endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding

I am having issues getting a connection to a NetTcpBinding up and running. I was able to get an Http binding and a Named Pipe binding working however Tcp is giving me a large amount of trouble. I have tried many different things thus far but none have worked.

I have read that the issue might be in the max buffer size for the client binding and I upped the maxBufferPoolSize, maxBufferSize, and maxReceivedMessageSize to their maximum. That had no effect. I have read the issue may be port sharing so I enabled port sharing on my machine but that had no effect either. I also disabled the firewall on the machine but that too didn't change anything.

The exact error I am getting is:

> CommunicationException
>
> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error
> processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the
> remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket
> timeout was '00:00:59.8127832'.

From what I have read this is a sort of blanket exception when WCF doesn't exactly know what went wrong.

I am at a loss as to what I should attempt next. I hope you can help.

Here is the server configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="DummyServer.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MetaDataBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata/>
                    <serviceDebug />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="MetaDataBehavior" name="DummyServiceLibrary.DummyServiceA">
                <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
                contract="DummyServiceLibrary.IDummyService" />
                <endpoint address="mex"
                binding="mexHttpBinding"
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding"
                contract="DummyServiceLibrary.IDummyService" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/dummy" />
                        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/dummy" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <applicationSettings>
        <DummyServer.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="ServiceType" serializeAs="String">
                <value>A</value>
            </setting>
        </DummyServer.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Here is the client configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="DummyClient.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDummyService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IDummyService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/dummy" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDummyService" contract="DummyService.IDummyService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IDummyService" />
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8523/dummy" binding="netTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IDummyService" contract="DummyService.IDummyService"
            name="NetTcpBinding_IDummyService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <applicationSettings>
        <DummyClient.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="ClientEndPoint" serializeAs="String">
                <value>NetTcpBinding_IDummyService</value>
            </setting>
        </DummyClient.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

I hope you are able to find what I have been unable to.

**Edit #1**
I have been able to get the TCP end point up and running by defining a DNS.

Here is the new server endpoint definition.

```
            <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" contract="DummyServiceLibrary.IDummyService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
```

Here is the new client binding definition and client endpoint definition.

```
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IDummyService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
            hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
            maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>


        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8523/dummy" binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IDummyService" contract="DummyService.IDummyService"
        name="NetTcpBinding_IDummyService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
```

Comment: Are you using .Net 3.5 or .Net 4.0 ? It is important becasue there are "Default" WCF config settings that were added 4.0 that had to be explictly set in 3.5.

Comment: Can you supply a code fragment of how you are creating and opening your service client ?

Comment: I solved the issue but don't understand how doing so solved it. I am using .NET 4.0. `DummyServiceClient client = new DummyServiceClient(Properties.Settings.Default.ClientEndPoint); client.Open();`

Comment: See [here](http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/08/easing-the-pain-of-wcf-debugging/) to enable debugging in the future event of exceptions you don't understand. Also, was there a firewall active?